# Detail File IO error reporting in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, c++11

Is there any open source File IO library or easy way in C++ which reports a detail and exact errors for File IO. For examples; If user doesnt have the read or right permission - or if the disk got full etc.

Answer (score 0):

C style file ops do this by default, you just need to include `cerrorno` and `cstring` and use [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) after an unsuccessful file operation call:

```
hFile = fopen(fname, "r+b");
/*-- attempt to create the file if we can't open it for reading --*/
if(!hFile) {
    /*-- print out relevant error information --*/
    printf("Open File %s Failed, %s\n", fname, std::strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

That is of course if you use C style file operations. I think ifstream also supports these on most compilers.

A note, this functionality is not thread safe on some implementations. There is [`strerror_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r) on linux which is thread safe.